# How to add ribbon in excel web-addin in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, excel-web-addins

how can I add excel ribbon in **excel web addin** in  visual studio to create excel plugin

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your solution.
select "add", then select "new item".
select ribbon.